# Driving fast on gear 4 and smelling burnt smell after

Tags: honda, tires, smell, sienna

I was driving about 60 to 70mph on freeway on gear 4. Started smelling a burnt smell and ended up getting a flat tire. Was able to use spare tire, and was able to drive home no problem, but now I smell burning in the car. What does that mean?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please provide more detail about what happened in between "smelling a smell" and "sitting at the side of the road with a flat tire".  How many gears does your car have? Is it a manual or automatic?

Answer (score 7):

Most likely the smell came from the flat tire. If you still have the spare on the vehicle and the flat is still in the trunk, that's what you're smelling.

Comment: It can take quite a bit of time and fresh air to get that burned rubber smell out of the interior of your car.  Try driving with the windows down for a few days.

Comment: A few weeks ago, we were following a pickup pulling a camper trailer. The first hint of trouble was the burning rubber smell, followed by the smoke from the blown tire. We stopped to help out, and the smell lingered _outside_ for a good 30 minutes in a light breeze. I'm sure the smell is still inside the truck & camper.